# Quarkus JPA SQL ResultSet mapping

Tags: java, sql, jpa, quarkus

I was going through the currently available guides for Quarkus & JPA however I cannot find any example of SQL ResultSet mapping or any evidence it is supported at all in Quarkus.

I'm talking about the possibility to bind the result of an SQL query to a custom pojo without using an existing JPA entity. All examples I found extract records from 1 table only, pulling out lists of instances of the same JPA entity. However this is very unlikely a common use-case for real-world applications. Most of the times we have to work with not so trivial queries involving mix of fields from different tables joined or calculated fields.

SQL ResultSet mapping is a handy JPA feature that addresses this issue and yet I can't find how to use it with Quarkus.

As far as I know there're 2 ways to declare ResultSet Mappings in JavaEE:

- either declare them in orm.xml
- use the @SqlResultSetMapping annotation.
  Now I think Quarkus doesn't support orm.xml and I'm not sure it supports @SqlResultSetMapping.

Where would you add the @SqlResultSetMapping annotation ?  Would Quarkus understand it?
Does anyone have a working example of how to achieve this?

Comment: Quarkus does not document every feature of the libraries integrated.

@SqlResultSetMapping should just work - if not, I consider that a bug and you should open an issue for it.

btw. for other tips around efficient data access with Hibernate (and Quarkus) see this video https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjd2amW3L7wAhVHsKQKHY-0AdEQwqsBMAB6BAgEEAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJ-JB1SwCyv4&usg=AOvVaw2CFG0wYwTwzFabUTunEA9j and https://github.com/maxandersen/quarkus-insights-effective-persistence which is the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [dynamic instantiation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause)?

```java
public class CallStatistics {

    private final long count;
    private final long total;
    private final int min;
    private final int max;
    private final double avg;

    public CallStatistics(long count, long total, int min, int max, double avg) {
        this.count = count;
        this.total = total;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.avg = avg;
    }

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

CallStatistics callStatistics = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select new org.hibernate.userguide.hql.CallStatistics(" +
    "   count(c), " +
    "   sum(c.duration), " +
    "   min(c.duration), " +
    "   max(c.duration), " +
    "   avg(c.duration)" +
    ")  " +
    "from Call c ", CallStatistics.class )
.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: You can also use https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks. That works however it forces you use JPQL and it doesn't fit every scenario. More often than not I prefer to use native SQL queries

Comment: Yesterday a friend of mine accidentally got it working. Apparently he did nothing special. He has the **META-INF/orm.xml** file in the application with some declared  **<sql-result-set-mapping... >** elements and plain POJOs with the constructor having the same fields and it just worked out of the box. I remember trying that and Quarkus couldn't find the constructor. Now it works. Maybe something changed in the newer versions?